# How to get a byte given by its code in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code of a byte and I want to get corresponding bytes' sequence. For example, the code is `65`, the sequence should be `b'A'`. I know there is a simple way to do it:

```
b = chr(65).encode()
print(b)  # b'A'
```

But it seems to be too slow and overcharged because of converting to string in the middle. Is there a fast and elegant way to do same in Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `bytes` constructor:

```
>>> bytes([65])
b'A'
```

There is also the `to_bytes` method, mostly useful if the integer represents multiple bytes but it also works for 1:

```
>>> (65).to_bytes(1, 'big')  # big or little endian makes no difference for 1
b'A'
```

The other way is just indexing:

```
>>> b'A'[0]
65
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But it uses a list that may be too expensive regarding performance. I mean the list `[65]`.

Comment: @Fomalhaut it's probably hard to escape because the end result is also a sequence of bytes. For single bytes it's easier to just keep the int. And if your performance needs are such that this single list matters, maybe don't use Python...

Comment: @Fomalhaut: because `b'A'` isn't a byte. It's a _sequence_ of bytes. 65 is the byte.

Comment: Probably, you are right. But maybe it is possible to gain performance by a way that doesn't use useless intermediary objects like `list` or `str`.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: yes, the second method.